# Trying to Get Back to the First UIViewController of the App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I have a app that I am trying to reload the original viewcontroller from the MainViewController. There is no .xib the first view of the app is created in the AppDelegate. After I have loaded a couple UIViewControllers that did other things, I need to return to the original webView (ViewController) that was launched by the app on startup. I am really having a hard time getting anything to work that researched on the web. I just need a way to reload the original view that the app started with. Can anyone provide any possible solutions for me to try please?  I am running out of options to try.

Thank!

Comment: are you using UITabBarController or UINavigationController?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the rootViewController again.

In the app delegate use:

```
self.window.rootViewController = yourFirstViewController;
```

Good Luck!

EDIT:

Also, you can access to the app delegate globally using:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]
```

I published a little example project that will help you:

https://github.com/luisespinoza/ChangeViewController

Good Luck!

Comment: Hi Luis, I tried this once but maybe I did something wrong. Could you post an small example. I have tried and looked at so much code that I must be doing something wrong and stupid. I do think that this was the right way to go, but when I called the delegate, it did nothing. Thank you so much for your help. The people here have been a great help, and if I can get this one working, my boss might just keep me.  lol

Comment: I uploaded a sample code to github, it is a little iOS app that present a viewcontroller, with a view and a button, if you press the button will change the view controller. You will notice that the VC has change because the view backaground color will be set randomly. You have to read the changeVC method in AppDelegate to find the VC changing.

Comment: How can I find it in github? Can you provide me with the location please.

Comment: @Jon, if you go to the link that I posted, you will find the project. You can download the project as zip by clicking this link https://github.com/luisespinoza/ChangeViewController/archive/master.zip

Comment: Thank you! I found it on github and it works great. I was not adding the call back method. Although it is working there is a warning with the: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] reloadViewController]; "Instance Method not found return type defaults to id.  Do I need to worry about this?

Comment: For eliminating the warning. Go to the .m where you call [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] reloadViewController] and   import the AppDelegate.h and cast the delegate like: [(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] reloadViewController]

Comment: Jon, if this was usefull for you, remember to accept the answer. Good Luck!